# Pandas DataFrame - compare the first element of each row with other elements of the row

Tags: python, pandas

How to correctly compare the first element of each row with other elements of the row in a Pandas DataDrame?

Below the code which gives the correct result but I think it is not an optimal solution because of the required two transformations.

Source code:

```
    df = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3,1], [2,3,2,2], [3,3,5,3]])
    mask = (df.T == df.iloc[:,0]).T

    print(df)
    print(mask)
```

Result:

```
   0  1  2  3
0  1  2  3  1
1  2  3  2  2
2  3  3  5  3
      0      1      2     3
0  True  False  False  True
1  True  False   True  True
2  True   True  False  True
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site, this question, since purely coding related, might be more suitable to be asked on https://stackoverflow.com/

Comment: Should I delete my question here?